# Accessing device attached to VPN router

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I wonder if its possible to access a device that is connected to a router which is connected to a VPN. From another device that is connected to the same VPN?

[image: picture shows an network map]

Router 1 is a ASUS RT-AC68U and runs OpenVPN 
Router 2 is a ASUS RT-AC68U that connects to router 1s VPN 
Device 1 is connected to router 1 
Device 2 is connected to routers 1s VPN

Comment: Yes; It should be possible to communicate with two devices connected to the same VPN.  This is how you allow an external device to connected to an intranet, by exposing the VPN to the internet, and by allowing a device to authenticate remotely into your intranet.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the nature of the VPN involved, as it creates a virtual
network between all the devices that are connected to it.

If devices on the VPN are allowed to see each other, there is no reason that
one device wouldn't be able to connect to another.

(This is a general answer to a very general question.)